# Not Getting any transaction page when integrating CCAVENUE Payment Method

Tags: php, ccavenue

Hello Sir/Ma'am I am having a problem when adding CCAVENUE payment gateway method to my website...I downloaded the kit from ccavenue site and I am using PHP kit...I got the Encryption Key (32 bit) and my merchant ID and put it in code and put some data directly there to test the code.
but when i run the code on server it says " Kindly activate the encryption feature and collect the TEST IP address by sending an email to service@ccavenue.com, please mention your TEST IP to be whitelisted and your registered URL." I already have the URL with key and it redirects me to http://www.ccavenue.com/?_event_transid=2182034325 this URL and no payment option I am getting there .... So Can anyone tell me where I am doing mistake ... Thank you for any help

```
Params.php file-->
    <form method="post" action="checkout.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount : </td><td><input type="text" name="Amount" value="10.00"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Order Id : </td><td><input type="text" name="Order_Id" value="test_r1234"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Redirect URL : </td><td><input type="text" name="Redirect_Url" value="redirecturl.php"></td>
            </tr>

            The Billing details of the customer have to be mandatorily sent via the below mentioned parameters. Please note this has to be authentic data else the transaction would be rejected by the risk team.

            <tr>
                <td>Bill Name : </td><td><input type="text" name="billing_cust_name" value="test"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bill Address : </td><td><input type="text" name="billing_cust_address" value="testtesttesttest"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bill Country : </td><td><input type="text" name="billing_cust_country" value="test"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bill State : </td><td><input type="text" name="billing_cust_state" value="test"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bill City : </td><td><input type="text" name="billing_city" value="test"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bill Zip : </td><td><input type="text" name="billing_zip" value="400064"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bill Tel : </td><td><input type="text" name="billing_cust_tel" value="test"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bill Email : </td><td><input type="text" name="billing_cust_email" value="test"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ship Name : </td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_cust_name" value="test"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ship Address : </td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_cust_address" value="test"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ship Country : </td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_cust_country" value="test"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ship State : </td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_cust_state" value="test"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>delivery city : </td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_city" value="test"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ship Zip : </td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_zip" value="400064"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ship Tel : </td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_cust_tel" value="654564465"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Delivery Notes : </td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_cust_notes" value="test"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>PayType: [dummy values, please contact service@ccavenue.com for actual bank short codes]: </td><td><input type="text" name="payType" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Billing Page Heading : </td><td><input type="text" name="billingPageHeading" value=""></td>
            </tr>



    </td>

                </tr>


            <tr>
                <td colspan='2' align='center'>
                    <INPUT TYPE="submit" value="submit">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

2. checkout.php

<?php
/*
    This is the sample Checkout Page JSP script. It can be directly used for integration with CCAvenue if your application is developed in JSP. You need to simply change the variables to match your variables as well as insert routines (if any) for handling a successful or unsuccessful transaction.
*/
?>

<html>
    <head><title>Sub-merchant checkout page</title></head>
    <body>

    <?php
        require("libFunctions.php");
        $Merchant_Id = "$Merchant_IDValue"; //This id(also User_Id)  available at "Generate Working Key" of "Settings & Options"
        $Order_Id = $_REQUEST['Order_Id'];      //your script should substitute the order description here in the quotes provided here
        $Amount = $_REQUEST['Amount'];          //your script should substitute the amount here in the quotes provided here
        $Redirect_Url = "$my_site"; //your redirect URL where your customer will be redirected after authorisation from CCAvenue
        $WorkingKey = "$Work_Key";      //put in the 32 bit alphanumeric key in the quotes provided here.Please note that get this key login to your 
        $ccaRequest="";
        $pname="";
        $pvalue="";                 //CCAvenue merchant account and visit the "Generate Working Key" section at the "Settings & Options" page. 

        $Checksum = getChecksum($Merchant_Id, $Order_Id, $Amount, $Redirect_Url, $WorkingKey);
        $keys = array_keys($_REQUEST);
        for($index=0;$index<sizeof($keys);$index++)
        {
            $pname = "".$keys[$index];
            $pvalue = $_REQUEST[$pname];
            $ccaRequest .= $pname . "=" . $pvalue . "&";
        }
        $ccaRequest .= "Checksum=".$Checksum;
        exec("java -jar ccavutil.jar  $WorkingKey \"$ccaRequest\" enc",$encRequest);
    ?>
 Kindly activate the encryption feature and collect the TEST IP address by sending an email to service@ccavenue.com, please mention your TEST IP to be whitelisted and your registered URL. 

            <form method="post" name="redirect" action="http://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp">   

            <input type=hidden name=encRequest value="<?php if(is_array($encRequest))echo $encRequest[0]; ?>">
            <input type=hidden name=Merchant_Id value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['Merchant_Id'] ?>">
        </form>
    </body> 
    <script language='javascript'>document.redirect.submit();</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register your host/IP address with CCAvenue. 
Go to this URL : https://login.ccavenue.com/jsp/merchant/merchantLogin.jsp

Login to your Merchant account.

Then go to the window that displays Merchant ID & Access code.

Check the "**Website URL**" section.

It should contain the host/IP address that you're using to send requests to CCAvenue. 
If not contact support and ask them to configure your **host**.

Then use the Access Code & Encryption Key Appropriate for the registered "**Website URL**"

Hope this helps.

Comment: @tharindu_DG Any idea  how to read response parameters thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152613/ccavenue-get-payment-status-from-response-url