# ccavenue get payment status from response url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am using iframe approach in a .net mvc app and we are setting one return url while sending the request.
My question is how can i know the payment status & ccavenue payment reference no and other payment related params from response url

My retun url action is something like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ResponseCCPayment()
    {
        //but how to read reposne params from here   
        return Content("got response frm ccveue");

    }
```

From CCAvenue documentation i can see 
redirect_url    CCAvenue will post the status of the order along with the parameters to this URL

But no details on what parameters. Can someone help to get this

Answer (score 0):

- Login to the **merchant account**. There you have an option to download the relevant documents about the returned parameters list. (Merchant Account : https://login.ccavenue.com/jsp/merchant/merchantLogin.jsp)
- In the Merchant Account you can configure a url to which a **asynchronous response** will be sent when a customer has made a payment. In this asynchronous response, you can get those payment related info.
- There is also a separate  REST api method, that takes the order id as argument and return payment related details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i use iframe and i mention a return url so in this case can i read response

Comment: I'm not sure of that since I implemented this months ago..... But you definitely can get an asynchronous response and also use separate REST api calls to check the payment status and request payment related info.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple in .NET C# to get ccavenue payment status.
Use the live URL for the production environment;
use the test URL for the test environment.

```cs
public void CCAvenueStatus(string OrderNo, string TrackingId)

{

            string decResponse = "";
            try
            {
                var LiveUrl = "https://api.ccavenue.com/apis/servlet/DoWebTrans?command=orderStatusTracker&version=1.2&request_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&access_code=";

                var TestUrl = "https://apitest.ccavenue.com/apis/servlet/DoWebTrans?command=orderStatusTracker&version=1.2&request_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&access_code=";

                var Key = "Keyxxxxxxxxx";
                var Code = "Codexxxxxxxxx";

                var reqParam = new StatusEncRequest();
                reqParam.order_no = OrderNo;
                reqParam.reference_no = TrackingId;

                string ccaRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reqParam);
                CCACrypto ccaCrypto = new CCACrypto();
                string strEncRequest = (ccaCrypto.Encrypt(ccaRequest, Key));

                var curl = TestUrl + Code + "&enc_request=" + strEncRequest;
                var client = new RestClient(curl);
                var request = new RestRequest(curl, Method.Post);
                RestResponse restResponse = client.Execute(request);
                var response = restResponse.Content;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
                {
                    NameValueCollection Params = new NameValueCollection();

                    string[] segments = response.Split('&');
                    foreach (string seg in segments)
                    {
                        string[] parts = seg.Split('=');
                        if (parts.Length > 0)
                        {
                            string KeyParam = parts[0].Trim();
                            string Value = parts[1].Trim();
                            Params.Add(KeyParam, Value);
                        }
                    }

                    string status = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Params["status"]) ? "" : Params["status"];
                    string enc_response = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Params["enc_response"]) ? "" : Params["enc_response"];
                    string enc_error_code = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Params["enc_error_code"]) ? "" : Params["enc_error_code"];

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status) && status == "0")
                    {
                        decResponse = ccaCrypto.Decrypt(enc_response, Key);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**